# Can I establish port forwarding with a remote server behind a load balancer?

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding, tomcat, load-balancer

I have an application on a remote development server that is running two separate nodes, each on a different port. Between those nodes and the actual front end is a load balancer. The problem I'm having is that I need to do some remote debugging to diagnose problems in the code. In theory I should be able to set up port forwarding between the 'debug' port I configured in tomcat and an open port on my local machine. In practise I'm not sure how to do that. To establish and ssh connection to the remote server, I have to supply a port argument to tell it which node to connect to. I also have to set up the forwarding from the debug port.

I tried doing something like `ssh myremote-server -p 8080 -L 9595:127.0.0.1:5005 -N` but the connection simply times out before it ever establishes. After a few minutes it returns to the command line with the message

> ssh: connect to host myremote-server port 22: Operation timed out.

What am I doing wrong? Is there some other way to set up a connection for remote debugging in a scenario like this?

After looking at the output message, I think I have a better idea of what is happening, but I still don't know how to fix it. The remote server is using a non-standard ssh port, hence the need to use the '-p' flag to connect. For some reason, the command I am running is ignoring the specified port and trying to connect on the default '22' port. Just to be sure, I tried a telnet with both ports. The custom port connects, but 22 times out. How do I get ssh to connect on the correct port?

Comment: can you connect to SSH for a shell session? being able to do so is more or less prerequisite to using SSH as a tunnel. so ssh is running on 8080, your debug port is 5005 (and is on the server you are SSHing into), and your localport is 9595? is that what you intend to do? have you set up port forwarding to expose SSH?

Comment: @FrankThomas I can successfully ssh into the server (ssh myremote-server -p 8080). I'm not sure about setting up port forwarding. When I have done this in the past (on different servers) I didn't have to do any additional steps, but it is possible it was already set up there.

Comment: Your commentary doesn’t match your description in your last edit to your question

Comment: @Ramhound What is not matching?

Comment: "I can successfully ssh into the server (ssh myremote-server -p 8080)." vs "The remote server is using a non-standard ssh port, hence the need to use the '-p' flag to connect. For some reason, the command I am running is ignoring the specified port and trying to connect on the default '22' port."

Comment: @Ramhound I can connect to the remote server via ssh or telenet using the custom port (8080 for the purposes of this question). The port forwarding should also be using this port, but according to the error, it is attempting to use the default ssh port (22) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/276501/ssh-tunnel-with-different-ssh-port).

I needed to put the remote server information as the second half of the command. The correct `ssh` command looks like this:

> ssh -L 9595:127.0.0.1:5005 -N myremote-server -p 8080

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation (See also: [Accept Your Own Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/).